# Ошибка подключения к серверу ***.***.***.***:3000 - Connection refused

Tags: php, curl

На сервере хранится node-js файл, который при обращении с нужными параметрами выдаёт html страницу с необходимой информацией. При обращении через браузер - всё работает, ответ приходит. При обращении через curl - ошибка следующего содержания: Failed to connect to ***.***.***.*** port 3000: Connection refused.
Манипуляции с сервером не возможны, т.к. сервер не мой. 
Код для получения информации стандартный:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://***.***.***.***:3000/comment/?projectUrl='. $pr_url .'&userUrl=' . $us_url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $html;
echo "<br>".$error;
```

Советы по типу "перезагрузить сервер" или "проверьте порт" - пожалуйста, мимо, проблема вовсе не в этом. Сервер и порт работают, но php файл не может получить оттуда данные. Подскажите, пожалуйста,  где может быть собака зарыта?

> [image: ---]

Скриншот отработавшего скрипта.

Сервер у другого разработчика, не мой.

Comment: Покажите, например, скриншот из браузера, чтобы мы убедились, что действительно работает. И первые два числа в IP-адресе

Comment: А сервер где? А то сейчас выяснится, что он у вас на локальной машинке

Comment: может у Вас файрволл или что-то еще в сети например?

Comment: Вы неправильно параметры передаёте в скрипте.

Comment: Еще меня смущает надпись Cannot GET на главной

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl = curl_init()  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://***.***.***.***:3000/comment/?projectUrl='. $pr_url .'&userUrl=' . $us_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
echo $out;
curl_close($curl);
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: Не помогло, ответ тот же.

Comment: Фаервол не при чем, пробовал запускать на двух разных машинах в разных сетях.